# Rotate hexagon in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, html5-canvas

everyone.

I found this awesome jquery plugin bu Max Lawrence at https://github.com/AndrewListat/HexagonProgress (I don't know why Max doesn't have a repository for this). It is MIT and I am trying to rotate the hexagons so it shows a point on the top.

This is how it generates:

[image]

this is how I need it?

[image]

It generates a canvas and can have an image inside. I am planning to use it as avatars showing the gamification progress around them.

Can you guys help me on this?

In the future, I am planning to convert it to vanilla-js (open source too) but right now, I can't understand the math beind the hexagon render.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a property called `starting angle` that's set equal to "`Math.PI`" and that might control the orientation of the hexagon. If it does, I bet a couple minutes of experimentation with settings like "`Math.PI / 2`" and "`Math.PI / 3`" would coax the secrets from it.

Comment: The startAngle property only rotates the progress bar, not the whole hexagon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried to play with the settings and added some CSS to rotate the canvas.

Added a starting angle **0** to set the start point of the line and added the CSS to rotate the canvas by **90 deg**.

JS:

```
$('#hexagon').hexagonProgress({
       value:0.54,
        startAngle: 0,
        animation:true,
        lineWidth: 5,
        lineCap: "round",
        clip: true
    });
```

CSS:

```
#hexagon canvas{
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Please see the js fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/p6hc49b0/

Comment: The css approach works but only if you don't use the background property of the plugin. It will rotate the image too.